# if condition on radio button check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to javascript and i am trying to insert multiple conditions in an if statement.

below my js.

```js
if (($("#chkIs_3").is(":checked")) && ($(document.getElementById("two").checked == false) && $(document.getElementById("four").checked == false)))
            {
                alert("Please check one vehicle type.");
            }
```

If and only if the id's(two, four) are unchecked the alert has to be shown, but for me even if one of the radio buttons is checked the alert is shown.

Please help me in rectifying the probelem.

id = chkIs_3 is a checkbox
id = (two & four) are radio buttons.

Comment: `if ($("#chkIs_3").is(":checked") && document.getElementById("two").checked == false && document.getElementById("four").checked == false)` Why are you creating jQuery object with `boolean` value?

Comment: Please update your snippet with relevant HTML and CSS to make a [mcve] - also you meant `$(("#two")`, not `$(document.getElementById("two")` - perhaps `if ($("#chkIs_3").is(":checked") || !$("#two").is(":checked") ||!$("#four").is(":checked"))`

Comment: `$(document.getElementById("two").checked == false)` looks like a jQuery object containing a truth value. You don’t need `$` at all here.

Comment: Also try to avoid mixing jquery and vanilla, try to decide which one you prefer and use that. You could do `if ($("#chkIs_3").is(":checked") && (!$("#two").is(":checked") && !$("#four").is(":checked")))`

Comment: i suggest dont mix vanilla js and jquery so it is not confusing and much cleaner

Comment: i have to write condition when the radio button is unchecked. can i write it as $("#two").not(":checked") ?

Comment: thank you @nicowernli . i got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing native Javascript with jQuery, for a start. You're also doing

```js
$(document.getElementById("two").checked == false)
```

...which is just weird and not valid. The dollar sign `$` is just a normal variable name. In this case jQuery is using it as its main function name.

---

This is what you need instead (in case you're not aware, the exclamation mark `!` means "not" and *inverts* the result of the `$("#two").is(":checked")`):

```js
if ($("#chkIs_3").is(":checked") && (!$("#two").is(":checked") && !$("#four").is(":checked")))
{
    alert("Please check one vehicle type.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I am very new to jquery and hence dint no.